# How can i have a interface check in typescript switch statements?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redux, interface, switch-statement

**I am using Typescript and redux**

I want to compare passed action with an interface and then perform the task

```js
export function counterReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: CounterActionTypes
): CounterState {
  switch (action) {
    case IncrementAction:
      return { ...state, count: state.count + action.incBy };
    case action as DecerementAction:
      return { ...state, count: state.count + action.decBy };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check into type guards for that.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

I would probably use `redux-toolkit` or `redux-actions` for that because it simplifies a lot your code and it has Typescript support

Comment: I compared using `switch(action.type)` and then did this to make typescript happy `(action as IncrementAction).incBy`

Comment: exactly, you basically doing the casting afterwards with the `as` operator. This is because you are doing that check on runtime with he switch. When doing things at runtime you want to by using typeguards.

just not to repeat yourself look at redux toolkip or redux actions. 

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice

I wouldn't use raw reducers with the number of tools that you have out there